# Need help making an Assembly program using records

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

In the following program, i'm trying to obtain the length of the longest name between the records.

The program is a exercise from the book Learn to Program With Assembly.

```
.section .data

.globl people, numpeople
numpeople:
    .quad (endpeople - people)/PERSON_RECORD_SIZE
people:
    .ascii "Gilbert Keith\0"
    .quad 200, 10, 2, 74, 20
    .ascii "Jonathan Barlett\0"
    .quad 280, 12, 2, 72, 44
    .ascii "Gilbert Keith Chesterfield\0"
    .quad 150, 8, 1, 68, 30
    .ascii "Tommy Aquinas\0"
    .quad 250, 14, 3, 75, 24
    .ascii "Isaac Newn\0"
    .quad 250, 10, 4, 70, 11
    .ascii "Gregory Mend\0"
    .quad 180, 11, 5, 69, 65
endpeople:

.globl NAME_OFFSET, WEIGHT_OFFSET, SHOE_OFFSET
.globl HAIR_OFFSET, HEIGHT_OFFSET, AGE_OFFSET
.equ NAME_OFFSET, 0
.equ WEIGHT_OFFSET, 32
.equ SHOE_OFFSET, 40
.equ HAIR_OFFSET, 48
.equ HEIGHT_OFFSET, 56
.equ AGE_OFFSET, 64

.globl PERSON_RECORD_SIZE
.equ PERSON_RECORD_SIZE, 72
.globl _start

.section .text

_start:
    leaq people, %rbx

    movq numpeople, %rcx

    movq $0, %rdi

    movq $0, %rdx

    cmpq $0, %rcx
    je finish

mainloop:
    movb NAME_OFFSET(%rbx, %rdx, 1), %al

    cmpb $0, %al
    je nextstring

    incq %rdx

    jmp mainloop

nextstring:
    cmpq %rdi, %rdx
    cmovgq %rdx, %rdi

    addq $PERSON_RECORD_SIZE, %rbx

    movq $0, %rdx

    loopq mainloop

finish:
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

The problem is that the value that the program returns is 13, which is the size of the first name, not the longest name.

Another thing i  noticed, is that **numpeople** is storing the value 4 instead of 6.

Comment: Could you explain what you expect the layout of  your `people` file to be?  Right now, each string has a different length and consequently, the following fields begin at random offsets from the beginning of the records.

Comment: My understanding was that records would be stored in sequential memory addresses. Once the \0 character was found, I would just need to add the total size of each record to the %rbx register, which would point to the next record. Also, in the books says that the names were padded with additional character but those are irrelevant, since \0 delimits the name size.

Comment: The book might say the names are (or should be) padded, but the way you coded it they are not. Hence the size of the records is variable.

Comment: Records can be stored any way you like.  C will store struct (their name for record) as a fixed sized item, making indexing into an array of struct easy to do by simply knowing that fixed size.  Databases often support variable length records, which means more complex calculations to access one element after another, but they also create indexes to make searching & sorting easy.